# Is it known that there are an infinite number of odd solutions for the Collatz conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Take all odd numbers that are non-divisible by 3.  These are in the form of 2(3n)+1 and 2(3n+2)+1.

Simplify:

2(3n)+1

6n+1

Find 3n+1:

3(6n+1)+1

9n+2

---

Simplify:

2(3n+2)+1

6n+5

Find 3n+1:

3(6n+5)+1

9n+8

Take any number 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, or 8 mod 9.  Repeatedly multiply by 2 until you get 2 or 8 mod 9.  There are infinite number of numbers that fulfill this criteria, as mod multiplication is cyclic.  Then find the n in 9n+8 or 9n+2 from this number.  Substitute the n into 6n+1 or 6n+5.  There are an infinite number of n and an infinite number of 6n+1 or 6n+5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand what you've written in the body of the question - you need to be clear about what, exactly, you're trying to prove at each stage - but it is indeed known that there are infinitely many odd numbers for which the Collatz conjecture holds. For example, suppose $2^n-1$ is divisible by $3$ (which will happen for infinitely many $n$ - if $2^n-1$ is not divisible by $3$, then $2^{n+1}-1$ is). Then $x={2^n-1\over 3}$ is odd (since $2^n-1$ is), and the Collatz sequence beginning with $x$ goes $$x, 2^n, 2^{n-1}, 2^{n-2}, . . . , 8, 4, 2, 1.$$